# How to fill fields in a popup when opening a sharepoint website with selenium using python?

Tags: python, selenium, sharepoint

With the use of selenium and python I am trying to develop automated web/GUI tests for sharepoint pages. The issue I have is the authentication, which is presented in form of a window/popup/alert/I_dont_know as follows

[image]

In the code I have tried the following combinations (based on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27322871/handling-authentication-required-alert-box-with-python-2-7-selenium-webdrive)):

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
authDomains = "http://bfh.col.garaio.ch"
        profile.set_preference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", authDomains)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("http://bfh.col.garaio.ch/_layouts/closeconnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true")    

alert = driver.switch_to.alert()

#alert = driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
alert.send_keys('USERNAME')
alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
alert.send_keys('PASSWORD')
alert.accept()
```

I tried windows and alert, but in the `alert`-case nothing happens, and in the `window` case I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

probably there is no `window` in `driver.window_handles`..

How can I fix this in order to send the username and the password to that box? It should for for firefox, chrome and IE as I intend to use selenium for functional testing of those sharepoint pages. For that reason, I need to log in as different users to be able to test permissions...

Addition:

- The code execution seems to hang in this line: `alert = driver.switch_to_alert()`

Comment: Do you get past this popup if you add the username and password in the url as in `driver.get("http://<username>:<pass>@bfh.col.garaio.ch)` ?

Comment: I tried that idea before many times - now this approach seems to work! Maybe sharepoint was very slow at this point ... I will investigate in more detail tomorrow and will get back to you...

Comment: @Alex Have your problem been resolved already? I've meet the same problem as you and can't find the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
import win32com.client 
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
time.sleep(2)
shell.Sendkeys(user)  
time.sleep(2)
shell.Sendkeys("{TAB}")
time.sleep(2)
shell.Sendkeys(pwd) 
time.sleep(2)
shell.Sendkeys("{ENTER}")
```