# How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using python?

Tags: java, python, selenium

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java) an answer is given on how to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using *Java*. Now, can this be used also for python? It looks like the python driver has no class `UserAndPassword` like the Java pendant has.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())
    alert.authenticateUsing(UserAndPassword("user","passwd"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is no such class in python selenium library, but you can easly navigate to given alert and input user and password using other means.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.send_keys('username')
alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
alert.send_keys('password')
alert.accept()
```

This will work on standard authentication, if it is custom made one you will probably have tinker with it abit.

Comment: No does not work. I suppose the authentication box I am presented is not an 'alert', but something else. So, an alert is never present. But a box is. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789858/how-to-fill-fields-in-a-popup-when-opening-a-sharepoint-website-with-selenium-us for an example how this box looks like...