# Chrome alert pop up not detected in Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, basic-authentication

I am having issues with handling Authentication pop up in Chrome via Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('URL')
time.sleep(5)
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.send_keys('Username')
alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
alert.send_keys('Password')
```

This returns an error--

> "selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no alert open"

Alternatively, I also tried the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://Username:Password@URL')
```

The second code works partially-

In Chrome the user is logged in but the page does not load. Only a blank page is displayed. Once the blank page is loaded, i passed only the URL(without user credentials) and it works fine.

In Firefox, the webpage loads perfectly.

Basically, the issue is with Chrome.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try sending the username and password along with the url.

Comment: I tried that. In the alternative code that I have posted in my question, I'm sending the username and password along with the url. But that doesn't load the webpage properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium Alert -- Prompt username and password is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328654/python-selenium-alert-prompt-username-and-password-is-not-working)

Comment: can you share the url in which you are getting the alert or popup

Comment: @Hiten, I cannot share the url due to confidentiality issues and even if I did, you wouldn&#39;t be able to access it unless you have an authorised VPN connection.

Comment: Okay.
Then check the url's source code.
Is there any iframe ?
If yes, then use that url for login and it will work.

Comment: I believe the alert pop up is invoked by JS. I cannot see source code before logging in and I'm very sure there's no iframe. 
I did find a workaround though, edited the question to highlight that.

Comment: Hey , did you find the solution. I got the same issue while adding an extension. WebdriverWait never detects the alert, when it is there. 
URL : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browsec-vpn-free-and-unli/omghfjlpggmjjaagoclmmobgdodcjboh?hl=en
When I click add extension, the alert popped is never detected by selenium.

Comment: @AhsanRoy Nope i did not. I did find a partial solution though. It is the second part of the post. Or you can check another question tagged to this post by DebanjanB. This might help you as well - [Handling “Authentication Required” alert box with Python 2.7 + Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27322871/handling-authentication-required-alert-box-with-python-2-7-selenium-webdrive)

Answer (score 0):

The second code you have tried is correct with a slight mistake.

```
public void loginToSystem(String username,String password, String url){
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://"+username+":"+password+"@ "+URL);
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your input. 

The code you have suggested doesn't look very different from mine. Except that you are using variable and I was passing them directly. Kindly point out what exactly is wrong in my code.

Also in your code, have you given a space character after '@'? When I tried that, the space inserted %20 after https:// eventually making the url incorrect.

My issue with the second code was that the web page was not loading properly. A blank screen was displayed.
As a temporary workaround I passed the url again after a wait time of 5 seconds and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

First try to wait for alert present.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
```

if alert is present then only move forword to next step.
And also can you please check the screenshot if alert is actually present when testcase is failing.

Comment: The time.sleep() provides sufficient delay until the pop up occurs. 
Yes, the alert is present when the script fails.

Comment: If it is giving NoAlertPresentException, it means there is not alert present.

Comment: You can just check this approach , Inspect the elements and find their xpath or id's and try with following code element = driver.find_element_by_id('userName')   element.send_keys('Username')  follow the same approach for password and submit button. Hope this will work for you.